# How do i bind NSImage array to a NSCollectionView

Tags: cocoa, binding, nsimage, nscollectionview, nsimageview

I have a NSCollectionView, whose view contains an Image Well. (NSImageView)
I have an array of NSImage.
I am able to bind the array to the NSCollectionview using Value > Collection View Item > representedObject

So that i see the number of items in the Collection View.

All i want is how do i bing the NSImage (present in Array - in an Array Controller) to the NSImageView (present in view of NSCollectionView)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you should do:

1. Place an Array Controller in IB and set the **Content Array** binding, for example, to the File's Owner, and set the Model Key Path to your array of icons.
2. Bind your Collection View's **Content** to your Array Controller, set the **Controller Key** to *arrangedObjects*.
3. On your view (NSImageView, ImageWell or button or whatever) bind the **Image** to the Collection View and set the keypath to *representedObject.myimage* (*myimage* must be a property of the objects contained in your array)

There are a few other bindings and outlets linked in IB (itemPrototype, View), but I believe those are set automatically when dragging these items into your xib file.

Comment: var  arrCategory:[NSString] =
    ["Australia","Austria","Belgium","Brazil","Cameroon","Canada","Chile","China","Denmark","Argentina"]
& let cell = collectionView.makeItem(withIdentifier:"CollectionViewItem", for:indexPath) as! CollectionViewItem & another cell line here  cell.imageView?.image = NSImage(named:(self.arrCategory[indexPath.row]).png)
help me out how to get  this image of array in swift 3.0 in NS collection view in swift 3.0